# attribute type in UML

Tags: uml

for example I have declared in my class the next attribute:

```
private Map<ArrayList<Object>, Object> obmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

What is a correct characterization in UML?

```
-obmap: LinkedHashMap<ArrayList<Object>, Object>>;
```

or probably something else?

Comment: What is the primary driver for asking about the _correct_ characterization? For example, when I look at your example, I can think of multiple ways that I might choose to represent `obmap`, depending on the different ways that I may want to highlight different aspects of that object across different architectural views or specific design viewpoints. Unless you are using code generation or some other type of model-driven tools for your development, I would view correctness more in terms of the best depiction to support each diagram and the intent of that view.